# Posts do not get shown in custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I am inserting posts with a custom post type `ga_reports` into the database.

With the following query I get the following result:

`SELECT * FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta m WHERE p.post_status =  'draft' && m.post_id = p.ID`

```
| ID  | post_author | post_date        | post_status | post_type  | meta_id | post_id | meta_key                  | meta_value                   |
|-----|-------------|------------------|-------------|------------|---------|---------|---------------------------|------------------------------|
| 524 | 1           | 17.08.2016 20:26 | draft       | ga_reports | 1610    | 524     | _                         |                              |
| 524 | 1           | 17.08.2016 20:26 | draft       | ga_reports | 1611    | 524     | ganalytics_settings       | NULL                         |
| 524 | 1           | 17.08.2016 20:26 | draft       | ga_reports | 1612    | 524     | _ganalytics_settings      | field_5779133493ecc          |
| 524 | 1           | 17.08.2016 20:26 | draft       | ga_reports | 1613    | 524     | wpgamail_options          | NULL                         |
| 524 | 1           | 17.08.2016 20:26 | draft       | ga_reports | 1614    | 524     | _wpgamail_options         | field_5777cc1bdebdd          |
| 526 | 1           | 17.08.2016 21:04 | draft       | ga_reports | 1619    | 526     | ganalytics_settings       | a:7:{s:16:"google_auth_code" |
| 526 | 1           | 17.08.2016 21:04 | draft       | ga_reports | 1620    | 526     | _ganalytics_settings      | field_5779133493ecc          |
| 526 | 1           | 17.08.2016 21:04 | draft       | ga_reports | 1621    | 526     | wpgamail_options          | NULL                         |
| 526 | 1           | 17.08.2016 21:04 | draft       | ga_reports | 1622    | 526     | _wpgamail_options         | field_5777cc1bdebdd          |
| 527 | 1           | 17.08.2016 21:04 | draft       | ga_reports | 1623    | 527     | ganalytics_settings       | a:7:{s:16:"google_auth_code" |
| 527 | 1           | 17.08.2016 21:04 | draft       | ga_reports | 1624    | 527     | _ganalytics_settings      | field_5779133493ecc          |
| 527 | 1           | 17.08.2016 21:04 | draft       | ga_reports | 1625    | 527     | wpgamail_options          | NULL                         |
| 527 | 1           | 17.08.2016 21:04 | draft       | ga_reports | 1626    | 527     | _wpgamail_options         | field_5777cc1bdebdd          |
| 528 | 1           | 18.08.2016 04:42 | draft       | ga_reports | 1628    | 528     | ganalytics_settings       | a:6:{s:16:"google_auth_code" |
| 528 | 1           | 18.08.2016 04:42 | draft       | ga_reports | 1629    | 528     | _ganalytics_settings      | field_5779133493ecc          |
| 528 | 1           | 18.08.2016 04:42 | draft       | ga_reports | 1630    | 528     | wpgamail_options          |                              |
| 528 | 1           | 18.08.2016 04:42 | draft       | ga_reports | 1631    | 528     | _wpgamail_options         | field_5777cc1bdebdd          |
| 529 | 1           | 18.08.2016 04:42 | draft       | ga_reports | 1632    | 529     | ganalytics_settings       | a:7:{s:16:"google_auth_code" |
| 529 | 1           | 18.08.2016 04:42 | draft       | ga_reports | 1633    | 529     | _ganalytics_settings      | field_5779133493ecc          |
| 529 | 1           | 18.08.2016 04:42 | draft       | ga_reports | 1634    | 529     | wpgamail_options          |                              |
| 529 | 1           | 18.08.2016 04:42 | draft       | ga_reports | 1635    | 529     | _wpgamail_options         | field_5777cc1bdebdd          |
| 530 | 1           | 18.08.2016 04:42 | draft       | ga_reports | 1636    | 530     | ganalytics_settings       | a:7:{s:16:"google_auth_code" |
| 530 | 1           | 18.08.2016 04:42 | draft       | ga_reports | 1637    | 530     | _ganalytics_settings      | field_5779133493ecc          |
| 530 | 1           | 18.08.2016 04:42 | draft       | ga_reports | 1638    | 530     | wpgamail_options          |                              |
| 530 | 1           | 18.08.2016 04:42 | draft       | ga_reports | 1639    | 530     | _wpgamail_options         | field_5777cc1bdebdd          |
| 532 | 1           | 18.08.2016 05:00 | draft       | ga_reports | 1643    | 532     | ganalytics_settings_copy  | a:6:{s:16:"google_auth_code" |
| 532 | 1           | 18.08.2016 05:00 | draft       | ga_reports | 1644    | 532     | _ganalytics_settings_copy | field_57b53f5217e16          |
| 532 | 1           | 18.08.2016 05:00 | draft       | ga_reports | 1645    | 532     | wpgamail_options          | NULL                         |
| 532 | 1           | 18.08.2016 05:00 | draft       | ga_reports | 1646    | 532     | _wpgamail_options         | field_5777cc1bdebdd          |
| 533 | 1           | 18.08.2016 05:00 | draft       | ga_reports | 1647    | 533     | ganalytics_settings_copy  | a:7:{s:16:"google_auth_code" |
| 533 | 1           | 18.08.2016 05:00 | draft       | ga_reports | 1648    | 533     | _ganalytics_settings_copy | field_57b53f5217e16          |
| 533 | 1           | 18.08.2016 05:00 | draft       | ga_reports | 1649    | 533     | wpgamail_options          | NULL                         |
| 533 | 1           | 18.08.2016 05:00 | draft       | ga_reports | 1650    | 533     | _wpgamail_options         | field_5777cc1bdebdd          |
| 534 | 1           | 18.08.2016 05:01 | draft       | ga_reports | 1651    | 534     | ganalytics_settings_copy  | a:7:{s:16:"google_auth_code" |
| 534 | 1           | 18.08.2016 05:01 | draft       | ga_reports | 1652    | 534     | _ganalytics_settings_copy | field_57b53f5217e16          |
| 534 | 1           | 18.08.2016 05:01 | draft       | ga_reports | 1653    | 534     | wpgamail_options          | NULL                         |
| 534 | 1           | 18.08.2016 05:01 | draft       | ga_reports | 1654    | 534     | _wpgamail_options         | field_5777cc1bdebdd          |
```

As you can see there should be several draft posts available for `ga_reports`.

Still I get in my custom post type nothing:

[image]

`ga_report` posts are created/updated the following way:

```
function createOrUpdateGaReports($ganalytics_settings,  $wpgamail_options, $id) {

    global $wpdb;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();       

    # get $id of ga_reports post and modify it, update the ganalytics_settings of this post and use the main config only in the first instance    
    if( TRUE === get_post_status( $id )  ) {
        //post exists

        // Update post 37
          $my_post = array(
              'ID'            => $id,
              'post_title'    => 'Report-' . $current_user->user_login . '-' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
              'post_content'  => $current_user->user_email,
              'post_type'     => 'ga_reports',
          );

        // Update the post into the database
        wp_update_post( $my_post );

        //update via acf
        //$ganalytics_settings
        $field_key = "field_57b53f5217e16";
        update_field( $field_key, $ganalytics_settings, $my_post['ID'] );

        //$wpgamail_options
        $field_key = "field_5777cc1bdebdd";
        update_field( $field_key, $wpgamail_options, $my_post['ID'] );

    } else { 
        //post does not exist

        $my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => 'Report-' . $current_user->user_login . '-' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
          'post_content'  => $current_user->user_email,
          'post_status'   => 'draft',
          'post_author'   => $user_id,
          'post_type'     => 'ga_reports',
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        $my_post = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

        //update via acf
        //$ganalytics_settings
        $field_key = "field_57b53f5217e16";
        update_field( $field_key, $ganalytics_settings, $my_post);

        //$wpgamail_options
        $field_key = "field_5777cc1bdebdd";
        update_field( $field_key, $wpgamail_options, $my_post);
    }
}
```

I checked the browser cache, which is not the problem.

Still the posts do not get shown. Any suggestions why?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace this code

$my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => 'Report-' . $current_user->user_login . '-' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
          'post_content'  => $current_user->user_email,
          'post_status'   => 'draft',
          'post_author'   => $user_id,
          'post_type'     => 'ga_reports',
        );

with:

$my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => 'Report-' . $current_user->user_login . '-' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
          'post_content'  => $current_user->user_email,
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => $user_id,
          'post_type'     => 'ga_reports',
        );